# python3 mime and file object not working

Tags: python-3.6, mime

I'm trying to use the below mail function  for python3 which is throwing  error `NameError: name 'file' is not defined` which its works perfectly for python2.

I got to know `file() is not supported in Python 3` what will be substitute of `file`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
############ File comparison & sendmail part starts here ########
def ps_Mail():
    filename = "/tmp/ps_msg"
    f = file(filename)
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        mailp = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['To'] = "sam@seemac.com"
        msg['Subject'] = "Uhh!! Unsafe process seen"
        msg['From'] = "psCheck@seemac.com"
        msg1 = MIMEText(filename.read(),  'text')
        msg.attach(msg1)
        mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
ps_Mail()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code and this should work, please try this...

There are two key things to change `universal_newlines=True` and use `open()` instead of `file()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
############ File comparison & sendmail part starts here ########
def ps_Mail():
    filename = "/tmp/ps_msg"
    f = open(filename)
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        mailp = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['To'] = "sam@seemac.com"
        msg['Subject'] = "Uhh!! Unsafe process seen"
        msg['From'] = "psCheck@seemac.com"
        msg1 = MIMEText(filename.read(),  'text')
        msg.attach(msg1)
        mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
ps_Mail()
```

For more details....

What is the difference between using universal_newlines=True (with bufsize=1) and using default arguments with Popen

The default values are: universal_newlines=False (meaning input/output is accepted as bytes, not Unicode strings plus the universal newlines mode handling (hence the name of the parameter though text_mode might have been a better name here) is disabled -- you get binary data as is (unless POSIX layer on Windows messes it up) and bufsize=-1 (meaning the streams are fully buffered -- the default buffer size is used).

universal_newlines=True uses locale.getpreferredencoding(False) character encoding to decode bytes (that may be different from ascii encoding used in your code).

If universal_newlines=False then for line in Robocopy.stdout: iterates over b'\n'-separated lines. If the process uses non-ascii encoding e.g., UTF-16 for its output then even if os.linesep == '\n' on your system; you may get a wrong result. If you want to consume text lines, use the text mode: pass universal_newlines=True or use io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout) explicitly.

The second version does include universal_newlines and therefore I specify a bufsize.

In general, It is not necessary to specify bufsize if you use universal_newlines (you may but it is not required). And you don't need to specify bufsize in your case. bufsize=1 enables line-bufferred mode (the input buffer is flushed automatically on newlines if you would write to process.stdin) otherwise it is equivalent to the default bufsize=-1.

Comment: while using `open` it throwing another error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`